# Keeping and checking Process alive in Java 1.7

Tags: java, performance

- How to make sure process (java.lang.Process) is alive in Java 1.7. In Java 1.8, there is isAlive() method. How can it be done in Java 1.7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably wait too late, but since I faced the same problem, here is my solution:
Just copy the implementation of the Process.isAlive() method from Java 8:

```
public boolean isAlive() {
    try {
        exitValue();
        return false;
    } catch(IllegalThreadStateException e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with out knowing  about the context of need of the Process. But in general, we could use Threads with  Executors framework..
Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
Then submit Tasks to it...

Answer (score 0):

I used the following for monitoring multiple processes launched through a Swing application. It follows the same logic mentioned by @mastah. See whether it helps.

```
package snippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ProcessMonitor extends Thread {

    private Process process;
    private int exitCode;

    public ProcessMonitor(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
        start();
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            exitCode = process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setOutputStream(final OutputStream s) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
                int c ;
                try {
                    while((c = is.read()) >= 0) {
                        s.write(c);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void setErrorStream(final OutputStream s) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                InputStream is = process.getErrorStream();
                int c ;
                try {
                    while((c = is.read()) >= 0) {
                        s.write(c);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitCode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if(args.length == 1) {
            System.err.println("In child process.. going to sleep for 1 second");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.err.println("In child process.. done sleep exiting...");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String[] pbArgs = new String[] {
          "java", "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"), ProcessMonitor.class.getName(), "arg"      
        };
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pbArgs);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        System.out.println("Starting process: " + pb.command());
        final Process process = pb.start();
        ProcessMonitor pm = new ProcessMonitor(process);
        pm.setOutputStream(System.err);
        while (pm.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("Process is still alive");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Process exited with: " + pm.getExitCode());
    }

}
```